# Deriving the constant relative risk aversion utility function

Tags: microeconomics, asset-pricing, risk-aversion

Here is the question I am trying to tackle:

Suppose that we are given a utility function $u$ with relative risk aversion $R_u$. Show that $R_u$ is constant and equal to $\rho$ iff there exist $\zeta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\eta>0$ such that
$$ u = \zeta + \eta D_\rho $$
where
$$ D_\rho(w)=\begin{cases}\frac{w^{1-\rho}-1}{1-\rho},&\text{if }\rho\neq 1\\ \log(w),&\text{if } \rho=1\end{cases}$$
In short, I do not understand the requirement for $\eta>0$. Here is my solution thus far:

Relative risk aversion is defined as
$$RRA=-w\frac{u''(w)}{u'(w)}$$
and we require
\begin{align}
RRA&=\rho\tag{1} \\
\frac{d}{dw}(RRA)&=0\tag{2}
\end{align}
We have,
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dw}(RRA) &= \frac{d}{dw}\Big(-wu''(u')^{-1}\Big)\\
&= -u''(u')^{-1} -w\Big(u'''(u')^{-1}-(u'')^2(u')^{-1}\Big)
\end{align}
From condition (2),
$$ u''+wu'''-w(u'')^2(u')^{-1}=0$$
Substituting in condition (1), $-wu''(u')^{-1} = \rho$,
\begin{align}
u'' + wu''' + \rho u'' &=0\\
(-\rho-1)u'' &= wu'''\rightarrow u'' = \kappa w^{-\rho-1}
\end{align}
for some arbitrary constant $\kappa$. Then
\begin{align}
u'&=\int \kappa w^{-\rho-1} dw\\
&= \eta w^{-\rho} + c
\end{align}
for some arbitrary constants $\eta$ and $c$. Then
\begin{align}
u = \int \eta w^{-\rho}+c\text{ }dw = \begin{cases}\eta\frac{w^{1-\rho}}{1-\rho}+cw+C,&\text{if }\rho\neq 1\\ \eta\log(w)+cw+C,&\text{if } \rho=1\end{cases}
\end{align}
for some arbitrary constant $C$. Clearly, condition (1) requires that $c=0$, i.e.
\begin{align}
u &= \begin{cases}\eta\frac{w^{1-\rho}}{1-\rho}+C,&\text{if }\rho\neq 1\\ \eta\log(w)+C,&\text{if } \rho=1\end{cases}
\end{align}
Since $C$ is arbitrary (i.e. our two conditions are satisfied by any $C$), we can rewrite this in the representation given by the question. Showing the reverse, that that the representation in the question is *sufficient* for the two conditions to be met, is trivial.

My question is, why do we *require* $\eta>0$? Is it a mistake in the question or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

This is just a consequence of the (here tacit) assumption that $u'>0$.

Comment: Apparently not, see my answer below

Comment: @PhilipHartfield, well, in your third equation below you take the $log$ of $u'$, which of course presupposes that $u'>0$.

Comment: You are completely correct! Then as far as I can see $\eta > 0$ is just a consequence of their solution and is presumed; will have to raise this with the TA.

Comment: @PhilipHartfield, I'd rather say that $u'>0$ is presumed, but this should not be too surprising in the context of utility functions...

Comment: True, but still seems backwards for a question designed to be rigiorous to ask you to show $\eta$ is necessarily greater than zero when it isn't without making an assumption not given by the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution from class,

\begin{align}
    -w\frac{u''(w)}{u'(w)} &= \rho\\
    \frac{u''(w)}{u'(w)} &= -\frac{\rho}{w}\\
    \frac{d}{dw}\big(\log u'(w)\big) &= \frac{d}{dw}\big(\log w^{-\rho}\big)\\
     \int\frac{d}{dw}\big(\log u'(w)\big)dw &= \int \frac{d}{dw}\big(\log w^{-\rho}\big)dw\\
    \log u'(w) &= \log w^{-\rho}+C\\
    e^{\log u'(w)} &= e^{\log w^{-\rho}+C}\\
    u'(w) &= e^{C}w^{-\rho}\\
    u'(w) &= \eta w^{-\rho}, \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\eta\equiv e^C>0
\end{align}
As VARulle points out, in the 3rd line it is assumed that $u'(w)>0$.